# how to vertically center query hint text within SearchView

Tags: android, android-studio, searchview

I set the custom font on my searchView text but after that my query hint text went little upward how an I vertically center it??

[image]

my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_250sdp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_16sdp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:background="@drawable/searchview_bg"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/relativelayout2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/notification_icon"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
        app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:queryHint="Search"
        app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/filter_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_filter"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

my java file

```
    Typeface tf = ResourcesCompat.getFont(getContext(),R.font.poppins);
    searchView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
    searchText = (TextView)searchView.findViewById(androidx.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    searchText.setTypeface(tf);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because your font has this bottom padding. Have you tried:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Another possible issue could be the gravity

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Comment: I used `searchText.setIncludeFontPadding(false);` in java and it worked for me Thank you:)

Comment: Yes! That would be the programmatically way to do it!